# Converting a numpy.ndarray value from bytes to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.4

I'm using numpy and Python 3.4 to read data from a .csv file.

Here is a sample of the CSV file:

```
"05/27/2016 09:45:37.816","187666432","7921470.8554087048","0","95.202655176457412","82.717061054954783","1.4626657999999999","158","5"
"05/27/2016 09:45:38.819","206884864","10692185.668858336","0","101.33018029563618","93.535551042125718","2.4649584999999998","158","5"
```

And here is my code sample used to extract data from the CSV above:

```
import os
import numpy as np

path = os.path.abspath('sample.csv')
csv_contents = np.genfromtxt(path, dtype=None, delimiter=',', autostrip=True, skip_header=0,
                             usecols=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))

num_cols = csv_contents.shape[1]

for x in np.nditer(csv_contents):
    print('Original value: {0}'.format(x))
    print('Decoded value: {0}'.format(x.tostring().decode('utf-8')))
    val = x.tostring().decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').replace('"', '')
    print('Without hex and ": {0}'.format(val))

    try:
        print('Float value:\t{0}\n'.format(float(val)))
    except ValueError as e:
        raise e
```

Sample output:

```
Original value: b'"187666432"'
Decoded value: "187666432"���������
Without hex and ": 187666432
Float value:    187666432.0

Original value: b'"7921470.8554087048"'
Decoded value: "7921470.8554087048"
Without hex and ": 7921470.8554087048
Float value:    7921470.855408705

Original value: b'"0"'
Decoded value: "0"�����������������
Without hex and ": 0
Float value:    0.0
```

In my `for` loop, to convert the `x` value to a float, I've had to do this:

```
val = x.tostring().decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').replace('"', '')
```

Which is not particularly elegant and prone to be faulty.

**Question 1:**
Is there a better way to do this?

**Question 2:**
Why does `x.tostring().decode('utf-8')` evaluate to something like `"158"���������������` when dealing with integers? Where are the hexadecimal coming from in `x.tostring()`?

Comment: which version of numpy are you using? Can you print the output of `list(b'"187666432"')` etc. for these values (perhaps that will explain the �s).

Comment: I'm on numpy 1.11.0. For your other request, I'll check once I'm back on my laptop! :)

Comment: Perhaps it's a fixed length value, filled with some `\0` or something like that? All three decoded values have the same length: `"187666432"���������` 
`"0"�����������������` 
`"7921470.8554087048"`

Comment: @luis Ah yes, the dtype is s20.

Comment: Your code works perfectly here, also with numpy 1.11.0, it outputs: `Original value: b'"0"'` 
`Decoded value: "0"` 
`Without hex and ": 0` 
`Float value: 0.0`

Comment: @Luis What Python version? I'm running this on 3.4.4 on Mac OS X 10.11 with numpy 1.11.0 (just double checked).

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE Running on Python 3.4.3, Ubuntu, numpy 1.11.0. I ran it on IPython, but just checked that it runs in python directly as well. Maybe some OSX-EndOfLine-Stuff? (ain't got no idea about OSX :P)

Comment: @Luis I am seeing the same issue on Windows 10, though. I'm not sure if its the same padding however. I'll have to check! Thanks

Comment: @HEADLESS_0NE Yeah, I cannot help you there, pal, it's beyond my knowledge :P Have fun! May it turn out easy and painless :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first question:

I strongly recommend using [pandas to read in csv files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
In [11]: pd.read_csv(path, header=None)
Out[11]:
                         0          1             2  3           4          5         6    7  8
0  05/27/2016 09:45:37.816  187666432  7.921471e+06  0   95.202655  82.717061  1.462666  158  5
1  05/27/2016 09:45:38.819  206884864  1.069219e+07  0  101.330180  93.535551  2.464958  158  5
```

*It "sniffs out" whether you have quoted strings, an  unquoted, though this can be made explicit.*

---

To answer the second question:

If you use flatten rather than nditer it doesn't add the `\x00`s (which make the length of each string to length 20; the s20 dtype):

```
In [21]: a
Out[21]:
array([[b'"187666432"', b'"7921470.8554087048"', b'"0"',
        b'"95.202655176457412"', b'"82.717061054954783"',
        b'"1.4626657999999999"', b'"158"', b'"5"'],
       [b'"206884864"', b'"10692185.668858336"', b'"0"',
        b'"101.33018029563618"', b'"93.535551042125718"',
        b'"2.4649584999999998"', b'"158"', b'"5"']],
      dtype='|S20')

In [22]: [i.tostring() for i in np.nditer(a)]
Out[22]:
[b'"187666432"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"7921470.8554087048"',
 b'"0"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"95.202655176457412"',
 b'"82.717061054954783"',
 b'"1.4626657999999999"',
 b'"158"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"5"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"206884864"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"10692185.668858336"',
 b'"0"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"101.33018029563618"',
 b'"93.535551042125718"',
 b'"2.4649584999999998"',
 b'"158"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
 b'"5"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']

In [23]: [i.tostring() for i in a.flatten()]
Out[23]:
[b'"187666432"',
 b'"7921470.8554087048"',
 b'"0"',
 b'"95.202655176457412"',
 b'"82.717061054954783"',
 b'"1.4626657999999999"',
 b'"158"',
 b'"5"',
 b'"206884864"',
 b'"10692185.668858336"',
 b'"0"',
 b'"101.33018029563618"',
 b'"93.535551042125718"',
 b'"2.4649584999999998"',
 b'"158"',
 b'"5"']
```

Comment: Thanks for `flatten`! I hadn't thought about changing the way I was iterating over my array.
I'll look into `pandas`; seems pretty handy.